# Hibernate : invalid ORDER BY expression

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hsqldb, ucanaccess

I have tried to add some Order to my `Criteria` like this.

```
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("priority")); // Not the real property though
```

And test on my System using a MsAccess database with HSQLDialect And i get

> Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid ORDER BY expression

So i tried to show the query, it reads like this :

```
Hibernate: 
/* criteria query */ select
    distinct this_.i_id as y0_ 
from
    T_FIT_ARTICLE this_ 
where
    (
        this_.b_export_ready=? 
        or this_.d_application_deadline>=?
    ) 
order by
    this_.d_application_deadline asc limit ? 
//FROM HERE THE STACK TRACE
```

the thing is, i used the `@OrderBy` annotation on my collection before, which produce the same query, and this works :

```
order by
    elements2_.i_order_nr asc limit ?
```

But with the attributes in my Entity, it causes exception.

By the way, if i try to test the same programm with `MYSQLSERVER`, it works perfectly.

Any idea why or how could i avoid this ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Why are you using the MS Access database with HSQLDB dialect?

Comment: @fredt because i connect with access via Ucanaccess, and ucanaccess uses this Dialect,
otherwise i tried MySqlServerDialect, same problem :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is still interested : The Problem was i set up an Projection of an Attribute and set Orders of another attribute. This is apparently not supported by the Dialect or the Database.